# Can using Jquery, I submit a form that belongs to different website

Tags: jquery, jsp

I want to fill a form and submit it using my application but the form that i am filling and submitting is a different webpage. Is this possible using Jquery or any other way.

Example: my application name formfiller( let the url be www.formxxxx.com) now i want using formxxxx/xyz.jsp i want to fill and submit a form  that is present on www.newURL.com..... is it possible? If yest how.

thanks
Rohit

Answer (score 2):

**No**. (at least using ONLY javascript)

See [Same Domain Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

**Edit:**

If you really have good reasons to do it so, you can [Ajax Cross Domain library](http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/) or do an implementation yourself after a read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe to put the form on your page.

Comment: hey Mark.... thanks for your reply but my application fetches the data that is needed to be filled in form.... so i dont want user to fill form rather automatically use that data to fill and submit form..... Any kind of suggestion to achieve this would be gr8.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not possible (XSS protection or something like that). The easiest way I can think of is using server-side code of your own that could act as a client and relay the request.